# UE4: Randomly spawning Blueprint Class actors inheriting from single C++ class

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I am making a system in Unreal Engine to spawn items my character can pick up. I have a single Item C++ class with this in the header file :

```
UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
bool Inventoriable;

UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
float Power;

UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
int Spawn_Weight;
```

In my Game Mode header, I have an array meant to hold all possible items

```
UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
TArray<TSubclassOf<AItem>> PlayerRecharge;
```

And in the cpp file, i have a SpawnPlayerRecharge() function that looks like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ITEMS; i++) {
    Item_Spawned = Cast<AItem>(PlayerRecharge[i]);
    if (Item_Spawned) {
        Total_Spawn_Weights += Item_Spawned->Spawn_Weight;
    }
}

// Choose random number for spawn selection
int Rand = FMath::RandRange(0, Total_Spawn_Weights);

// Iterates through spawnable items and tries to cast as Item object
// Weight variable stores the summed weights to compare to the random number
//if Weight > the random number, store the index in Weight and break from loop
int Weight = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ITEMS; i++) {
    Item_Spawned = Cast<AItem>(PlayerRecharge[Weight]);
    if (Item_Spawned) {
        Weight += Item_Spawned->Spawn_Weight;
        if (Weight > Rand) {
            Weight = i;
            break;
        }
    }
}

FActorSpawnParameters Params;
Params.Owner = this;

// Spawn AItem actor from the array based on index found above
GetWorld()->SpawnActor<AItem>(PlayerRecharge[Weight], SpawnPosition, SpawnRotation, Params);
```

Basically, all the types of items I have are in Blueprint classes that inherit from Item with different meshes, Power properties, etc. In SpawnPlayerRecharge(), I'm trying to randomly spawn one of the different types based on weights set in each child's Blueprint editor. In the function, the cast always fails (I checked with UE_LOG), and if I try to access the weights directly with PlayerRecharge[i], it gives me an error saying that UOBJECT does not have property Spawn_Weight. How do I get access to those Blueprint children, or is there a better way to do this?

If you need to see code I didn't post, it's on my GitHub: https://github.com/Chriq/BatteryMan

Comment: You're trying to cast an object of type TSubclassOf<AItem> to a AItem pointer, that's not the same.